# Disable RST for Installing ubuntu 20.4 Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo ideapad S340 (Intel i7 and SSD) and try to install Ubuntu 20.04 aside Windows 10.
Everything goes smooth until I am asked to disable intel RST.
Back in the bios, i select to change from RST to DH_something and get a warning telling me that i will (may) loose all data... I wont do that! I wont install linux since ubuntu allows for rst. So my question  :
More and more pcs will use RST mode .. When can it be made available.. a month, a year, more?

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed in RST mode with no problems. But I don't have Windows. ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6   Can you tell how you did it, or make a post about it?  Quite a questions/answers about installing Ubuntu with RST mentions it has to be disabled.  Ubuntu installer usually also suggests it can't install on RST system.

Comment: The problem is not that Ubuntu can't be installed with RST on. The problem appears if Windows is installed using some RST features. It always can be solved by re-installing Windows, etc. Without Windows there is no problem at all.

Comment: You can change safely but needs to done from Windows, see link.  You probably can also install Ubuntu in a VM.   https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Comment: @crip659 : The link you provide seems to be the right way to go https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci   Ill check asap.. assuming it works fine

Comment: Would google some about changing Windows to SATA, so you have good idea how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Intel RST**

You've got a single SSD/HDD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD/HDD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem. **Some users found Choice #2 to be easier**.

**Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!**

<strike>**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.</strike>

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
- Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
- If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: @GillesBONNET Not quite exactly correct, but close. Just follow the exact steps in the procedure.

Comment: thanks heynneman. (our comments were simultaneous// so I just summarize :
I saw your solution several times on the net so Ill give it a try.. In short, this is what I understood :
- prepare for a safe boot
- before the safe boot starts, enter bios
- modify the RST mode to  AHCI
- exit bios,windows boots in safe mode
- reboot normal

***** in a word : change bios from RST to AHCI  while windows is planned to start in safe mode  *****

Comment: @GillesBONNET Again... just follow the exact steps in the procedure :-)

Comment: : thanks a lot.My bad is i always like to figure out what  I do, not only copy a recipe !! your answer accepted..

Comment: I agree, it's good to understand what the steps are doing in plain English rather than blindly follow a set of instructions. Thank you so much for this guide, I was following the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/ and it didn't work. One thing to note in case this helps someone, when I rebooted in safemode, nothing worked in the start menu (Windows 11), I couldn't start any app and even when selecting the shell in the app list, I would get an error. I finally managed by opening the task manager (ctrl+alt+del), then select File -> Run New Task and then typed cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully executed Choice #2 today on Lenovo Legion 7-15IMHg05 worked like a charm.

When changing the mode in the BIOS it warned that data on the disk would be wiped. Fortunately it is only a precaution that did not happen.

Of course, before this procedure that took 5 minutes I have a Restore disk, Microsoft Installation Media and did a full backup. Apparently, like always, when you have these you do not need them.

Also note that while in RST, Acronis 2020 boot DOES NOT see the internal drive (did not try 2021). EaseUS Todo Backup DOES see the internal drive. So while in RST mode for this pc model I would prefer EaseUS.

In my case, F2 during boot enters the Bios. F12 during the book gives boot device options.
Ubuntu 18.04 is now installed side by side with windows.

Good luck to all.
Mickey

Answer (score 0):

this may be a late answer, but this works perfectly without changing anything as given in the accepted answer.

before starting the process keep the Backup of your data from the System

after backup follow the below given steps to disable the RST and install the OS you wished too

here are the steps to disable the RTS from the windows system.

1. Insert the Booted USB or CD.
2. while starting the PC/Laptop keep pressing the f2 button or any other according to the system to open the BIOS menu.
3. after opening the BIOS menu move to the Configuration tab.
4. at the bottom of the Configuration Tab you find the option names as `storage`,
   Click on that
5. after the `storage` Menu opens you find the DROPDOWN with ACHI and RAID SATA.
6. choose the ACHI from Dropdown and press f10 or any other according to the system to save the setting.
7. after step 6 PC will get shutDown or Restart, while starting keep press the f12 or any other according to the system to save the setting.
8. after doing the above steps correctly you will get the boot menu with the USB or CD you inserted.

above steps are tried and verified with the **Lenovo ideapad s340**

**Caution**: After this you won't get back the Winows and the Windows Key

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to disable the RTS from lenovo thinkpad x240

While starting the PC/Laptop keep pressing the f2 button or any other according to the system to open the BIOS menu.

After opening the BIOS menu move to the *Config* tab.

At the bottom of the Configuration Tab you find the option *power*, Click on that after the *power* Menu opens you find *Intel (R) Rapid Start Technology*

Press enter then choose *disable*
Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save your changes

Comment: You do not need to do that Ubuntu 20.04 will use RST.

Comment: Currently installed it and it had this error. It may help someone else facing the error in future too

Comment: Thank you for contributing, @gatwirival.  Please take the [tour]. Please use English to the best of your abilities when posting so that there is less for other volunteers to clean up. 
For instance, all English sentences begin with an uppercase letter. You should also have a look at how keyboard buttons can be formatted in questions and answers using HTML. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#:~:text=To%20reboot%20your%20computer,%20press%20%3Ckbd%3Ectrl%3C/kbd%3E