# HDD is not showing at the time of installing Ubuntu in my new 11th gen HP Laptop

Tags: 20.04, hp

I newly bought HP Notebook 15s-DU3032TU. It has 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7, 8GB DDR4, 1TB HDD, Windows 10 Home, MS Office, Integrated Graphics. I install a new HIKVISION 256GB NVME M.2 SSD in this laptop. I installed Windows 10 Home in SSD. At the time of installing Windows 10, at first no storage device was showing. So, I have to download Intel RST driver and install in at the time of Windows 10 installation. But, I want to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongsides Windows 10 Home. So, when I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, there is no HDD option showing, only SSD and Flash Drives are showing. But, I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in HDD. Both of HDD and SSD are set in UEFI mode and aslo my installation media.

Show how to slove my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable RST for Installing ubuntu 20.4 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281127/disable-rst-for-installing-ubuntu-20-4-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Intel 11th gen i5, however Ubuntu 21.04 installed easily. 
Probably because the technology was changed in 11th gen, Ubuntu 21.04 does support it now as documented here. It supports 11th Gen(Rocketlake).
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221?_ga=2.69553296.1024335101.1627191998-1624232675.1627191998

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 or 21 might be more helpful to use real version numbers.

Comment: Thanks, added versions