# "ubi-partman failed exit code 141" error while installing Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, usb-installation

I'm trying to switch from Windows 10 to Kubuntu 21.04 but, I keep getting this error:

```
ubi-partman failed exit code 141
```

After getting done filling out the Software options in the Kubuntu 21.04 installer, my mouse shows that something is being loaded. Then my fans kick in, and the error `ubi-partman failed exit code 141` gets thrown. I've tried installing about 5 times, and this happens every time.

If this helps at all, my laptop is an ASUS TUF GAMING. Secure Boot and Fast Boot are both not enabled.

Here is where I downloaded the ISO file: https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

Here is the exact ISO file/link I downloaded: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/21.04/release/kubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso

I verified the integrity of my ISO file by installing Kubuntu 21.04 using the same ISO file on a VM.

**Applications used to flash:**

- BalenaEtcher -- Yielded same result
- Rufus -- Yielded same result

**Currently Testing if RST/RAID is enabled and disabling it, will update with results.**

Methods for disabling RST:

- [Disable RST for Installing ubuntu 20.4 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281127/disable-rst-for-installing-ubuntu-20-4-dual-boot)

or

- https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000027232/technologies/intel-rapid-storage-technology-intel-rst.html

or

- https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/608239/disabling-rst

Maybe this is why I get this problem?

```
No Serial ATA RAID disks detected,
No matching physical volumes found, 
7/27/21 3:03 AM ubiquity    dbfilter_handle_status: ('ubi-partman', 141)
7/27/21 3:03 AM ubiquity    dbfilter_handle_status: answer 524288
7/27/21 3:03 AM activate-dmraid No Serial ATA RAID disks detected
7/27/21 3:03 AM partman   No matching physical volumes found
7/27/21 3:03 AM ubiquity    debconffilter_done: ubi-partman (current: ubi-partman)
7/27/21 3:03 AM ubiquity    dbfilter_handle_status: ('ubi-partman', 141)
```

The solution proposed in this article also failed:
https://programmerah.com/solution-to-ubi-partman-failed-with-code-141-when-installing-ubuntu-3551/

Although it didn't work, this might be useful information:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 28.65 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Glide    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00154753

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 60088319 60086272 28.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

---

None of this stuff is really important, just addressing some concerns and questions from comments.

- **Why do you want Kubuntu/Ubuntu/Linux?**

  I wanted Linux because I was first introduced to Linux in a Cybersecurity class and joined a club called CyberPatriot. Through this club I was assigned Ubuntu to have to secure, and quickly fell in love with how customizable, and open Linux was, so I decided upon installing a VM just to run Linux and play around with it on my own Windows machine. Although, I could never actually install Linux as I had too much stuff on my Windows machine, luckily this is a completely new PC so, I can finally fully enjoy Linux. I also feared that things I needed and used daily weren't going to be supported on Linux and luckily, they are all supported.

  I also had only 8 GB of ram about 7.8 GB usable RAM and Windows used 5 GB of that, keep in mind this laptop is for gaming and why that would become an issue, of course that can be fixed slightly (I tried everything I could) without Linux but, there was also a ton of intrusive applications built into Windows because of ASUS that made me go ahead and go through with just installing Ubuntu, I chose Kubuntu because of it utilizing KDE instead of GNOME, which I've heard was more customizable as trying to customize with GNOME becomes very difficult.
- **Addressing recommendation to use Kubuntu 20.04.**

  I honestly just don't like it as much as Kubuntu 21.04 visually which might be a dumb and shallow reason but yeah, I like Kubuntu 21.04s look a lot better. Also, yeah I had to deal with the `nomodeset` issue before within a VirtualBox VM luckily, Kubuntu 21.04 seems to interact well with my drivers at least for now.

Comment: 1. I would recommend that you **try with the newest version with long time support, 20.04 LTS**. It is more debugged and polished than 21.04 (with a 9-month life-time). Only if you have very new hardware, and need new hardware drivers, the version 21.04 might be better; 2. There can also problems because of the graphics chip/card, particularly if you have nvidia. Then you should boot with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Answer (score 1):

> https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/608239/disabling-rst
> WORKED!
>
> I needed to disable RST through my BIOS. I thought this setting wasn't available on my BIOS somehow, so I neglected this solution, but I finally found the setting.
>
> Thank you all for the help!

<sub>(Solution moved here from the OP's question)</sub>